# How to get going with Xamarin without compiling anything for iOS?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, xamarin, cross-platform

I am using Visual Studio 2015. I am trying to follow the basic tutorial of Xamarin from here

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/

When I get to the build part, I get problems, some of which because I don't have a Mac connected.

I only want to try things for now, and don't have any need for my app to work, or even compile for iOS, but still I want it to be written in Xamarin forms, just to learn how it works.

For Android, everything seems to compile, and my only physical device runs Android.

I would like to disable iOS and Windows build, and only remain with Android, and play around with that, and only later busy myself with Windows and iOS trouble.

How can I remain with only the portable and Android parts?

Comment: right click on the iOS project and either delete it or unload it

Comment: @Jason write it as an answer and I'll accept, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS and XS, you can right-click on a project in the solution and choose to either Unload or Delete.  Unload is temporary, Delete is permanent.